# Como fazer modal aparecer só uma vez de acordo com o check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Eu gostaria de alcançar o seguinte:

- No carregamento da página inicial, exiba a caixa modal
- Dentro da caixa modal, exiba um formulário com uma única caixa de seleção obrigatória
- Ao marcar a caixa de seleção, clique em enviar e feche a caixa modal, vá para a página inicial
- Lembre-se dessa preferência de seleção de caixa de seleção usando um cookie
- Quando os usuários retornam à página inicial, se marcarem a caixa de seleção, a caixa modal não será exibida

Eu já fiz a modal com o formulário mas não sei como manipulo o cookie pra pegar o resultado do click no check

Chamada da modal:

```
var openModal = document.getElementById('open-modal');
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-1');
var closeModal = document.getElementsByClassName('close-modal')[0];

openModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.toggle('visible');
});

closeModal.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.classList.remove('visible');
});
```

HTML da modal:

```
<button id="open-modal" class="button alert triger-modal" data-triger="modal-1" style="display: none">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal-wrap visible" id="modal-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">Tutorial de Primeiro Acesso!</h2>
          <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <img src="../../repo/files/:public:KnowSolutionsDashboard:Embed:tutorial.gif" style="display:block;margin:auto;" alt="Tutorial de Primeiro Acesso" /><br/>

          <label style="position:relative;z-index:99999;"><input type="checkbox" name="mensagem" id="tutorial" value="1" >Não mostrar essa mensagem novamente</label> <br>


        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `localStorage` para esta tarefa:

```
checkbox.onclick = function(){
    if(!this.checked) localStorage.mostrarModal = false;
}
```

E na função que se executa automaticamente para a abertura do modal, caso `localStorage.mostrarModal === 'false'`, impede a execução do resto da função, usando um return:

```
window.addEventListener('onload', function(){

    if(localStorage.mostrarModal === false) return;

    exibeModal();

});
```

Como pode ver, `exibeModal` nunca será executado.